# How is this In-browser lightweight animation done?

Tags: javascript, animation

I see a number of sites have auto-loading animation as soon as you scroll down to the particular part of the site with the animation - apple.com has it, most recently I found it on http://www.bugherd.com/features

I see a number of PNGs loaded in the web inspector but I can't determine how its being done.

Comment: Can you link to an example?

Comment: can you give us an example? Cant seem to find it on the apple site.

Comment: bugherd is the best example.  If you scroll down the page, the demo of the app begins playing.  jQuery Waypoint may trigger than animation as you scroll to the point - but I'm trying to determine HOW the animation is done.  It's all separate PNGs.

Comment: Apple used to have more animation done on the iPhone 4 page.  The earbuds here is a simple example: http://www.apple.com/iphone/design/

Answer (score 1):

it’s Matt (co-founder & designer @ BugHerd) here :)

Really glad to hear you like the animations we put together on the features page. In order to achieve the effect we used the transit.js library: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

It uses the same syntax as jQuery animations and uses the animation queue as well. I put together the animation by loading up all the images needed and then transitioning, hiding and showing as required.

Happy to answer any other questions you might have about how to implement this on your own site.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Also as an aside the animations on the Apple site are fairly complex, but there’s a pretty detailed run down of the techniques used to achieve their effects. It’s well beyond what we’re doing on BugHerd though :)

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1GWTMLjqQsQS45FWwqNG9ztQTdGF48hQYpjQHR_d1WsI

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're talking about, but if you are referring to the animations Apple had when presenting the iPad, it's easy to do.
What you do is bind an event listener to the page/container scroll event. Then, check if your element is in view range, by comparing its top offset to the scroll height. If it's in view, call a function to animate the element. This can be done either by a single image sprite animating the background-offset, or an actual image sequence or even a canvas - your call.

Comment: Hi Andrei, I meant the demo of bugherd specifically on that URL above.  If you click Play Demo, you see interaction being done, but it's not a movie file.

Comment: In that demo, they are just animating the elements themselves. Every layer is an html element and they are just moving them around using absolute positioning. The background is static and they only have a few keyframed movable parts (mouse, tooltip, popup, modal etc). If you look at the source code you can see each layer individually. Even when the text is input in the box in the first animation you can select it as normal page text.

Comment: Thanks - I was kinda able to discern that.  But where is the animation being calculated, in javascript? in CSS?  That's the part I couldn't find.

Comment: As far as I can see the animation is done using CSS transition properties added as inline style and triggered using JavaScript. It's pretty simple, really. Here, I made a [Pen](http://cdpn.io/paGKm) for you. Of course, they must be using some sort of library, don't ask me which though